# Contact form with Email & SMS in PHP

Tags: php, forms, email, sms, contacts

I am just a beginner in PHP,

I have created a landing page with simple contact form with - Name, Email & Phone fields, the PHP code is

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['contact-form-name'];
$email = $_POST['contact-form-email'];
$message = $_POST['contact-form-message'];

$to = 'name@example.com';
$subject = 'Subject';

$body = "";
$body .= "Name: ";
$body .= $name;
$body .= "\n\n";

$body .= "";
$body .= "Message: ";
$body .= $message;
$body .= "\n";

$headers = 'From: ' .$email . "\r\n";

//$headers = 'From: noreply@domain.com' . "\r\n";

//$body .= "";
//$body .= "Email: ";
//$body .= $email;
//$body .= "\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo '<span id="valid">Your Email was sent!</span>';
}else{
echo '<span id="invalid">Your message cannot be sent.</span>';
}
```

All we want now is get SMS as well as Email from the same contact form,

We are using Textlocal as our SMS gateway & there API allows as to send SMS using PHP, the send SMS code in PHP POST is

```
    <?php
    // Textlocal account details
    $username = 'youremail@address.com';
    $hash = 'Your API hash';

    // Message details
    $numbers = array(918123456789, 918987654321);
    $sender = urlencode('TXTLCL');
    $message = rawurlencode('This is your message');

    $numbers = implode(',', $numbers);

    // Prepare data for POST request
    $data = array('username' => $username, 'hash' => $hash, 'numbers' => $numbers, "sender" => $sender, "message" => $message);

    // Send the POST request with cURL
    $ch = curl_init('http://api.textlocal.in/send/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Process your response here
    echo $response;
?>
```

Need help in merging the both PHP's into one or making the both work,

So that we will get both Email & SMS

*Note the contact form validation is done custom.js

Thanks

Ashok

Comment: do both parts of the code ( ie: email and sms ) work independantly currently? ie: does it send an email and does the sms code send the sms?

Comment: You can put your sms code after the mail gets success response.
Check here-
<code> if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
//SMS code here
}else{
//error msg and sms will not be sent.
} </code>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both pieces of original code work and do what they are supposed to do you could nest the code like the following and send the sms based upon the success of sending the email.

```
<?php

    $status=array();

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['contact-form-name'], $_POST['contact-form-email'], $_POST['contact-form-message'] ) ){

        $name = !empty( $_POST['contact-form-name'] ) ? $_POST['contact-form-name'] : false;
        $email = !empty( $_POST['contact-form-email'] ) ? filter_input('contact-form-email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) : false;
        $message = !empty( $_POST['contact-form-message'] ) ? $_POST['contact-form-message'] : false;


        if( !$name || !$email || !$message ){
            $status[]='one or more required fields are empty';
        }

        if( empty( $status ) ){
            /* email elements */
            $to = 'name@example.com';
            $subject = 'Subject';
            $body = "\n
                Name: {$name}\n\n
                Message: {$message}\n";
            $headers = "From: {$email}\r\n";

            /* send the email - assign result as a variable */
            $result=@mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

            /* add a status based on mail sending */
            $status[]=$result ? 'Mail sent' : 'Mail could not be sent';




            if( $result ){

                $username = 'youremail@address.com';
                $hash = 'Your API hash';

                $numbers = array( 918123456789, 918987654321 );
                $sender = urlencode( 'TXTLCL' );
                $message = rawurlencode( $message );
                $numbers = implode( ',', $numbers );


                $data = array(
                    'username'  => $username,
                    'hash'      => $hash,
                    'numbers'   => $numbers,
                    'sender'    => $sender,
                    'message'   => $message
                );


                $ch = curl_init( 'http://api.textlocal.in/send/');
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                $response = curl_exec( $ch );
                curl_close( $ch );

                $status[]=$response;
            }
        }

    } else {
        $status[]='Invalid method';
    }

    /* process the various status messages stored in the array */
    echo "<h2>Status</h2><ul><li>", implode( "</li><li>", $status ), "</li></ul>";

?>
```

Comment: Hi Ram Raider, i tried the above code but i get this error message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Version 2.0\assets\php\sms.php on line 16"

Comment: There was a missing closing bracket `)` courtesy of Notepad+ auto-completion

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, but i am getting error saying "Invalid method"

Comment: if you look at `if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['contact-form-name'], $_POST['contact-form-email'], $_POST['contact-form-message'] ) ){` - are all these conditions met or have names of fields been changed from those shown here or are you using GET rather than POST???